# Enviar inteiro como string em um JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

Estou com um problema de retornar um valor inteiro muito grande no JSON tipo:

```
{“matricula”: 201737909200976697}
```

O que acontece é que no retorno está trazendo 201737909200976700.

Isso ocorre com qualquer inteiro grande como esse de 18 algarismos, então queria retornar esse valor como uma string mas no JavaScript ele ainda está chegando como valor numérico.

Como eu posso fazer para resolver isso?

**EDIT 1:**

Do php sai assim: ‌

```
array (  
  0 =>   
  array (
   'mtr_codigo' => '2586',
   'aln_nome' => 'JOSÉ FERNANDO REIS',     
   'mtr_matricula' => '201737909200976697'
  ),
)
```

Quando chega no javascript está:

```
[{"mtr_codigo": 2586, "aln_nome": "JOSÉ FERNANDO REIS", "mtr_matricula": 201737909200976700}]
```

**EDIT 2:**

No DevTools do chrome na parte response está assim:

```
{"body":[{"mtr_codigo":2586,"aln_nome":"JOS\u00c9 FERNANDO REIS","mtr_matricula":201737909200976697}],"meta":{"output":[]},"status":{"code":200,"phrase":"OK","type":"success"}}
```

Na parte preview está assim:

```
 body: [{mtr_codigo: 2586, aln_nome: "JOSÉ FERNANDO REIS", mtr_matricula: 201737909200976700}]
 0: {mtr_codigo: 2586, aln_nome: "JOSÉ FERNANDO REIS", mtr_matricula: 201737909200976700}
   aln_nome: "JOSÉ FERNANDO REIS"
   mtr_codigo: 2586
   mtr_matricula: 201737909200976700
 meta: {output: []}
 status: {code: 200, phrase: "OK", type: "success"}
```

**EDIT 3:**

No método que entrega o resultado estava com

```
json_encode($result, JSON_NUMBER_CHECK);
```

Removi esse parametro de options e retornou o valor númerico como string corretamente.

Comment: Eu realmente não consegui reproduzir esse problema, aqui funciona e chega como string, você está utilizando ajax? Se sim, como está seu codigo ajax e o código php exato que retorna o json para esse ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só você utilizar aspas para o valor:

```
{"matricula": "201737909200976697"}
```

Comment: Você tem acesso a fazer alteração no serviço que fornece o json ? Se sim, e for sever-side php, é só vc fazer um cast para string de uma forma que a saída fique como {"matricula": "201737909200976697"}, como o amigo acima falou

Comment: do php sai assim: ["id" => 2586, "nome" => "JOSÉ FERNANDO REIS", "matricula" => "201737909200976697"].


Quando chega no javascript está {"id": 2586, "nome": "JOSÉ FERNANDO REIS", "matricula": 201737909200976696}

Comment: Estranho, acabei de testar com o PHP retornando exatamente `json_encode(["id" => 2586, "nome" => "JOSÉ FERNANDO REIS", "matricula" => "201737909200976697"])` e no javascript chegou como string. Pode colocar um trecho do código na pergunta para ajudar?

Comment: Fui no método onde entrega a resposta e faz o JSON::encode e estava com um JSON_NUMBER_CHECK. Removi ele e retornou certinho o número como string.